# Can Xdefaults start automatically?

Tags: x11

I use Xdefaults to set the size and position of emacs windows.
Unfortunally,each time I log in system, I have to run xrdb ....

Is there a better way to do that?(without modify `.emacs`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enter your `xrdb` commands in your `$HOME/.xinitrc`.

Comment: write "xrdb ~/.Xdefaults" in .xinitrc ?

Comment: Yes. `.xinitrc` is sourced by the X server when you open an X session.

Comment: Try in `.xsession` then (or `.xsessionrc`, I never remember)

Comment: maybe it's my problem...not very familar with X windows.  .xinitrx need to be edited like shell script

Comment: @Wilbeibi: Good luck fighting GNOME. I hope [the `gnome-session` manpage can help you](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gnome-session) -- but the GNOME guys are notorious for not documenting their software much. :(